# How to parse a composite type to JSON in Postgres for Node

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a composite type for a column setup called email with the fields (email and verified). When I call select all through a query I get a response in the following format:

```
[{ ...(other fields), email: '(test@abc.com,f)'}]
```

How do I parse this to JSON so it get converted to:

```
[{ ...(other fields), email: { email: "test@abc.com", verified: false)}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to get such an output that you can produce with your own server-side JavaScript.

for example, i change  `...(other fields)` to `a: 1`

```js
var k = [{ a: 1, email: '(test@abc.com,f)' },
{ a: 2, email: '(hello@abc.com,t)' }];

for (var i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {
    var help = k[i].email.split(/[(,)]/gm)
    k[i].email = {
        email: help[1],
        verified: help[2] == 'f' ? "false" : "true"
    }
}
console.log(k);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest *not* to postprocess this with Javascript - but already do this on the `query` side:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9edg4MvKxJ7BUmHhhuAPjE/0

```
CREATE TYPE email AS (
  email text,
  verified boolean
);

CREATE TABLE emails (
  email email
);

INSERT INTO emails (email) VALUES (ROW('test@abc.com', false));
```

```
SELECT 
jsonb_build_object('email', (email).email, 'verified', (email).verified) as email
FROM emails;

-- {"email":"test@abc.com","verified":false}
```

This way it should be more performant/faster and side affects free from client code.

Comment: Although this would work I generally prefer to remove any additional work on the database level which can be handled by the API or UI. However this would definitely be useful for other scenarios